# Join tables sql not invalidated

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables like these:

```
create table classe (
id integer primary key,
name varchar not null
);

create table alunno (
id integer primary key,
id_classe integer not null
);
```

i would to take in a unique query the following data:

- classe.id
- classe.name
- count of alunno having a specific id_classe

so i can do something like this:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(b.id) 
from classe a, alunno b 
where a.id = :1 and b.id_classe = a.id;
```

but if the count = 0 I have null value in resultset..so i would to have always the info of stanza record and if no one alunno record is present for that stanza i would count = 0 that not invalidate the entire output..How can i have this resultset?

I tried also with left join but probably is wrong structured..

I add that i'm using SQLite so some SQL commands can not be used on it

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the joining condition in the `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, IFNULL(COUNT(b.id), 0)
FROM classe AS a
LEFT JOIN alunno AS b ON b.id_classe = a.id
WHERE a.id = :1
```

Answer (score 0):

`count(x)` counts only non-NULL `x` values, but `count(*)` counts all rows:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       count(*)
FROM classe AS a
LEFT JOIN alunno AS b ON b.id_classe = a.id
WHERE a.id = :1
GROUP BY a.id;
```

(You still need an outer join to get the `classe` rows without matches. The grouping is necessary only if you might search for more than one ID.)

Alternatively, use a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to look up the count:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM alunno
        WHERE id_classe = classe.id
       ) AS count
FROM classe
WHERE id = :1;
```